Intercept full and complete HTTP-traffic of a client-app
I want to get the complete traffic sent by a HTTP-request in the client itself.
Beginning from the "POST" to the last byte.
Is there a way to do so? Some sort of interceptor?
Not only logging in a file, but get it in the app (to have every byte sent also in a String or byte-array after sending - to do something with it - e.g. logging, archiving, ...).
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) new URL ("http://localhost/test").openConnection ();
http.setRequestMethod ("POST");
http.setDoOutput (true);
http.connect ();
OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream ();
os.write ("test".getBytes ());
InputStream is = http.getInputStream ();
byte [] resp = is.readAllBytes ();


"get it in the app" what do you mean? You need to clarify the question.

This sounds like you want to write your own iptables. It's OSS. You can check how it's implemented.

Use a library to handle the HTTP Client request.  This abstracts you from the low level opening of connections, etc but also allows you to enable wire-level logging as you desire.
There are many popular Java-based HTTP Client libraries.  Doubtless other people will list some in other answers.
If you use Apache HTTP Client, you can certainly enable the wire-level logging (see https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html) but also you can put other kinds of interceptors if you wish.
Be careful though about intercepting streams of data; you will need "tee" the data off for you own diagnostic purposes whilst also passing the data to the intended downstream consumer.
